# Is there a Hive equivalent of SQL “LIKE ANY ( SUBQUERY )”

Tags: syntax, hive, hiveql

While Hive doesn't supports multi-value LIKE queries which are supported in SQL : ex.

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE first_name LIKE ANY ( 'root~%' , 'user~%' );
```

We can convert it into equivalent HIVE queries as :

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE first_name LIKE 'root~%' OR first_name LIKE 'user~%'
```

Does anyone know an equivalent solution that Hive does support in case sub-query is used with LIKE ? Have a look at below example :

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE first_name LIKE ANY ( SELECT expr FROM exprTable);
```

As It doesn't have values in expression, I can't use same approach for generating multiple LIKE expression separated with OR / AND operator. Initially I thought to write HIVE UDF for it ?  Can you please help me supporting such expression and finding HIVE equivalent ?

Comment: The questions are 1 year apart so maybe the solution was not available when it was posted but I think this is the good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33626645/hive-query-with-multiple-like-operators

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hive's RLIKE relational operator as shown below,

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE first_name RLIKE 'root~|user~|admin~';
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a case involving theta joins in Hive. There is a wiki page for this and a jira request. Please go through the details here on this page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Theta+Join

Your case is similar to the **Side-Table Similarity** case given on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the expr values into a map and then use regular expression to find the like.  Alternatively you can also use union all with all the like expressions in separate SQL - the query might become tedious so you can programatically generate it.

Answer (score 0):

What about this using EXISTS

```
SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM exprTable WHERE first_name LIKE expr );
```