# Hive query with multiple LIKE operators

Tags: hive, sql-like

What would be the right way to write a Hive query with multiple LIKE operators like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
WHERE
some_col LIKE '%abc%'
OR
some_col LIKE '%xyz%'
OR
some_col LIKE '%pqr%'
OR
... (some more LIKE statements)
```

I tried doing the above as well as

```
WHERE some_col LIKE '%abc|pqr|xyz%'
```

but they didn't return any results. It works fine if I write separate queries, i.e.

```
WHERE some_col LIKE '%abc%' -> returns results
```

and

```
WHERE some_col LIKE '%pqr%' -> also returns results
```

Comment: There is no good reason for Hive to fail at processing multiple LIKE expressions combined by OR. Could you elaborate on the table type (external vs. managed, partitioned or not, Text vs. RCFile vs. Orc vs. whatever) and the column definition (a plain String? any Null values in there?)

Comment: `WHERE some_col rlike 'abc|pqr|xyz'` works.

Answer (score 21):

From the docs:

> A RLIKE B
>
> NULL if A or B is NULL, TRUE if any (possibly empty) substring of A
>   matches the Java regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. For example,
>   'foobar' RLIKE 'foo' evaluates to TRUE and so does 'foobar' RLIKE
>   '^f.*r$'.
>
> ---
>
> A REGEXP B
>
> Same as RLIKE.

So, use

```
WHERE some_col RLIKE 'abc|pqr|xyz'
```

Comment: Thanks @mattinbits! It works and able to write clean code

Answer (score 13):

You can probably use rlike(regular_expression).

```
WHERE some_col RLIKE '*abc*|*pqr*|*xyz*'
```

Comment: This is what I tried but did not get results. Are you suggesting that I try WHERE some_col RLIKE '%abc|pqr|xyz%'

Comment: Yeah, try with rlike for regular expression. Sorry for the typing error. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Does not work for me. I think it should be: WHERE some_col RLIKE 'abc|pqr|xyz'

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Earlier I was trying `column RLIKE '*abc*' OR column RLIKE '*pqr*' OR column RLIKE '*xyz*'`
But this was very heavy on processing. However if I put as mentioned int eh solution, it is working fine. Any explanation for this will be a help?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the issue might be you need to group the like statement. Your Example done:

```
SELECT * 
FROM some_table
WHERE
(some_col LIKE '%abc%'
OR
some_col LIKE '%xyz%'
OR
some_col LIKE '%pqr%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UNION` if you have to use multiple condition in `LIKE` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col LIKE '%abc%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col LIKE '%xyz%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_col LIKE '%pqr%'
```

Comment: OK, but that would probably require 4x more resources than a single query with ORs -- and if Hive fails at something as simple as boolean expressions, then it can fail at anything  :-/

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to check for a list of specific substrings, you could use a different approach e.g.

`WHERE InStr(some_col, 'abc') +InStr(some_col, 'pqr') +... >0`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions